# asp.net edit template using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, data-binding

I am using stored procedure to edit rows of data in listview control.Each Row has 'Edit' and 'Delete' link,so that when user clicks on 'Edit' the row should become editable.
The error I am getting is that when user clicks on 'Edit',row does not become editable.

stored procedure used is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RegisterUpdate]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@id int,
@fname nvarchar(50),
@lname nvarchar(50),
@company nvarchar(50),
@email  nvarchar(250)
```

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
-- Update statements for procedure here

    Update dbo.register
        SET fname = @fname, 
             lname = @lname,
            company=@company,
            email=@email
        WHERE dbo.register.id=@id
END
```

GO

Asp.net code is:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
          <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF; color: #333333;">
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="fname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fname") %>'>'></asp:TextBox>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="lname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("lname") %>'>'></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="company" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("company") %>'>'></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email") %>'>'></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="Save" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
                </td>
              </tr>

            </EditItemTemplate>
```

C# code used to save Data in dataset is:

```
 protected void ListViewDetails_ItemEditing(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.RegisterUpdate", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        }
```

Comment: Show the Markup where you define Edit Button of your ListView

Comment: Your Editing event handler has some mistakes. Other than that is there any error shown or its like that just clicking edit button, nothing happens ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets try with this it may help you.

```
protected void AdminUserControl_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        AdminUserControl.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        UserBLL userbll = new UserBLL();
        AdminUserControl.DataSource = userbll.GetAllUsers();
        AdminUserControl.DataBind();

    }
    protected void AdminUserControl_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        UserBLL userbll = new UserBLL();

        TextBox fname= (TextBox)e.NewValues["fname"];
        TextBox lname= (TextBox)e.NewValues["lname"];
        TextBox company= (TextBox)e.NewValues["company"];
        TextBox email= (TextBox)e.NewValues["email"];

        user = new User();
        user.fname= Convert.ToInt16(fname.Text);
        user.lname= lname.Text;
        user.company= company.Text;
        user.email= email.Text;

        admin.UpdateUsers(user);
    }
```

if you are using grid view then [see](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should bind values in ItemUpdating Method.
attach Handler with listview for ItemUpdating.

when update command is fired, you should use the code.

```
protected void ListViewDetails_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox fname = (TextBox)e.NewValues["fname"];
            TextBox lname = (TextBox)e.NewValues["lname"];
            TextBox company = (TextBox)e.NewValues["company"];
            TextBox email = (TextBox)e.NewValues["email"];


            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.RegisterUpdate", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;



            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", Convert.ToInt16(fname.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", company.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Code is updated... added `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` which will execute the command. may be you might get errors of parameters, that will be because you have to set and pass paramters which are expected into stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public void ListViewDetails_ItemEditing(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "??";

    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.RegisterUpdate", sqlConn)) {

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ????);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", (TextBox)e.NewValues["fname"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", (TextBox)e.NewValues["lname"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", (TextBox)e.NewValues["company"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", (TextBox)e.NewValues["email"]);

            try {
                sqlConn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                //handle exception
            }

            try {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                //handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Where do you get the User's ID from?**